# JavaScript Post Method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript and have stumbled upon something I'm struggling to fix.  I want to post data from a form to a server but upon clicking the submit button the it doesn't seem to be sending the information.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

JAVASCRIPT:

```
   $("#sendFeedbackButton").click(function(){
   $.post("Link to the server", $("#feedbackform").serialize())
   alert("Thanks for the feedback");
   });
```

HTML:

```
   <form id="feedbackform" name="feedbackform">
   <textarea id="name" name="name" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>
   <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
   <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
   <input type="button" id="sendFeedbackButton" value="Send feedback"/>
   </form>
```

Comment: What lead you to think that it doesn't send the information? Have you checked the network activity? Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is demo of `$.ajax`.
it response error server because I have no server, but if server would exist it should be ok.
you can see in the network that call made and it go to the error function in this demo because no server exist and do the alert.

http://jsfiddle.net/nn007/sAaLU/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("sendFeedbackButton").click(function(){
```

You forgot the `#`

```
$("#sendFeedbackButton").click(function(){
```

You have to use `#` for `id` and `.` for `class`

Examples

```
$('#id')
$('.class')
```

---

---

```
$("#sendFeedbackButton").click(function(){

   $.post("ajax-or-whatever-.php", $("#feedbackform").serialize(), function(response_from_server){ // this function runs after the infos have been sent and the server responded
        alert("Thanks for the feedback" + response_from_server);
   });

   return false; // don't let the form submit and refresh, instead run code above
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.  I've added it, but it still doesn't seem to correct the issue.

Comment: @user3058948 are you sure the link to the file is right? open your console, any errors? Check my update

Comment: I'm certain the link to the server is correct in my code.  There's no errors when I view the console, which is strange.  Upon clicking submit nothing happens.

Comment: @user3058948 add an `alert()` in the `click function` to see if it gets called

Comment: @user3058948: You don't get the alert either?

Comment: Oh right, there already is an alert... so.. your code is probably not at the end of `body` or not using `document ready`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$("sendFeedbackButton")
```

to

```
$("#sendFeedbackButton")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.  I've added it, but it still doesn't seem to correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#sendFeedbackButton").click(function(){
```

instead of

```
$("sendFeedbackButton").click(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sendFeedbackButton").click(function(){
$.post("Link to the server", $("#feedbackform").serialize())
alert("Thanks for the feedback");
});
```

notice the # in front of sendFeedBackButton